# Click on the top half of a button - doesn't work?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 Relative layouts :  ( *as you can see in the animation*)

- The green RelativeView
- The "*type something & icons*"  RelativeView
- The gray speperator RelativeView
- The bottom Textview

Each RelativeView is "below" it's previous relative view.

[image]

By design , when the 2 inner views are closed , the button should be **half** top above the green , and **half** bottom above the text ( just like the animation  shows)

Ok , So I added a button which is found inside the "bottom textview"

But in order for the bottom to be only half bottom above the view , I added it a negative Margin :

So [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zADnv.jpg) **without** the negative margin :

[image]

And [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7DdQ.jpg) with the negative margin ( the desired result)

[image]

So when I clicked the button I simply hide/show ( + animation with `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`) the inner  2  middle views

*So where is the problem ?*

**Question**

I don't know why but only the bottom half of the button is clickable ! I guess it is because that half is inside  its container view  while the top half is not in its view...( maybe i'm wrong)

But if I remove the negative margin and the button is fully in its container - then the button is 100% fully clickeable ( both top half and bottom half)

As you can see in the animation (last frames) - when i click the top half - nothing happens....

How can I fix that ?

Maybe i've taken a **wrong initial approach** ?

nb : [some more visualization of structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqwQ8.jpg) :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried translationY instead of margin?

Comment: @iTwenty please help me a bit more ? ( code maybe) ? i've been working on this whole day.... :-(

Comment: Try replacing `android:layout_marginTop = -32dp` in your button's xml with `android:translationY = -32dp`

Comment: @iTwenty tested , same result : the top half is not clickable.

Comment: Maybe, you'd like to have a look at the new Floating Action Button (FAB): http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons

Comment: negative margin causes your button to be outside parents View and would not get focus/click on this piece of view which is outside parent. I thing your approach is wrong and you should redesign layout - all in Relative, inside first view drawn will be showing/hiding View, then GreenView and at the end your button (over all of previosly created/inflated views). It causes some additional work for measuring and custom animating programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your button as a sibling to the RelativeLayouts rather than as a child. This works as you want it to.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">![enter image description here][1]

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:layout_below="@id/red"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_below="@id/green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/green"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hide Green"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Looks like this and the button moves up/down as setVisibility is toggled between GONE/VISIBLE for green RelativeLayout

[image: Looks like this and the button moves up/down as setVisibility is toggled between GONE/VISIBLE for green RelativeLayout]

Comment: I've decided to go with your solution. which works pretty ok ( the button is not moving  , but im gonna fix it) - so here is a question : if I have a view , how can I find the offset of its bottom ? ( in other words , after they all collapse - i need to "bring" the button to the bottom of the first view )  --- http://i.stack.imgur.com/9TSfy.jpg

Comment: The `View` class has `getTop()` and `getBottom` which are relative to the parent `ViewGroup`. As for the button not moving, if you can specify it's position relative to the view being animated, you can get it to move without any extra effort. In my example, if I animate the green `RelativeLayout`, the `Button` too moves as it has `layout_below = @id/green`

Comment: Got it !working ! I put the button as `_android:layout_below="@id/viewGray1"_`  ( the view gray is the separator , as you know already) with negative margniTop ( of course now the button is a sibling just like you said in the answer) and now it moves perfectly. thank you soooo much

Comment: Glad you got it working! :) BTW, how did you make that animated screenshot in your question?

Comment: [Regarding the gif recorder -here it is ask me for further assistant](https://cropper.codeplex.com/) , Regarding the solution : now I have another problem. I did exactly as you did ( I just hide the inner 2 views)  and it all works great. but look at the top half of the button when collapsing , it is faded with the gray view....help please:-) ? - see here http://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ498.gif ( how can i make it top half not to fade ???)

Comment: I assume it relates to HOW I hide the views ?e.g. `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` ?

Comment: Ok i solved it by adding my own animations . Removed the built in one

Answer (score 1):

Your button belongs to bottom RL. When android routes ACTION_DOWN it checks layout's borders and gives events to viewgrops (VG) which have event coordinates inside. Then VG proporate event to it's children based on it's coordinates.

So when you click on upper part of your button touch event given to grey RL and button which belonges to blue RL doesn't get it. Actually event given to Window -> Root ViewGroup -> Some Other ViewGroup -> View. And routing happens base on coordinates. It is true for ACTION_DOWN which starts touch, but not all MotionEvent processed this way.

As a solution, you can move button to another groupview which can route touch event properly. Or maybe try to use touch delegates.